# Floating Object is not iterable

Tags: python

let us consider following  code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
x =[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
y = [[2],[4],[6],[8]]
w = [[[1.477867]], [0.]]
print(len(w))
#define  y =k*x+b
def feed_forward(inputs,outputs, weights):
  out =np.dot(inputs,weights[0])+weights[1]
  squared_error =(np.square(out-outputs))
  return squared_error
def update_weights(inputs,outputs,weights,epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    org_loss =feed_forward(inputs,outputs,weights)
    wts_tmp = deepcopy(weights)
    wts_tmp2 = deepcopy(weights)
    for i in range(len(weights)):
       wts_tmp[-(i+1)] += 0.0001
       loss = feed_forward(inputs, outputs, wts_tmp)
       delta_loss = np.sum(org_loss - loss)/(0.0001*len(inputs))
       wts_tmp2[-(i+1)]+= delta_loss*0.01 
       wts_tmp = deepcopy(weights)
    weights = deepcopy(wts_tmp2)
  return wts_tmp2
weigths_new =update_weights(x,y,w,1000)
```

when i run this code, it shows me following error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

this error occurs at the following line

```
---> 20        wts_tmp[-(i+1)] += 0.0001
```

i did not get point of this error, because i used following  code

```
for i in range(len(weights)):
```

because when i have searched about this error, users says that use range command, i used and  i checked  as well by part and index works fine, so what is the source of error?thanks

Comment: `wts_tmp[-(i+1)]` is a list. You are trying to add a float to it.

Comment: Is `wts_tmp ` a dict?

Comment: no no, it is list,  i have tried to  add additional bracket, but still it does not work

Comment: And why is there a `-` in the brackets?

Comment: so point is that   number of  weights is  2 , therefore  i  will run in range of 2,which is [0, 1], and i want to access  first and last element of  list,maybe  i  thought incorrectly

Comment: I still don't understand why. Try printing the list before the for loop to see what's wrong

Comment: How can you get the error at line 20? Because only `for i in range(len(weights)):` can give that error. And `wts_tmp[-(i+1)]` can give only `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: i got point, now, because python indexing is from zero, and there is  2 element, i should use index zero and 1,i thing i  should use enumerate right

Comment: Just remove the -(i+1) and replace it by i

Comment: But even with that you shouldn't get that error. Try printing wts_tmp before the for loop

Comment: because i  did deep copy of weights, it means that wts_tmp  is also list right, as original weights

Answer (score 1):

You get a TypeError because at that moment `i = 0`, so `-(i + 1) = -1`, your list `wts_tmp = [[[1.477867]], [0.0]]`, so `wts_tmp[-1]` is the list `[0.0]` and when you attempt to do `wts_tmp[-1] += 0.0001`, python actually uses the inplace add special method `__iadd__` from `list` class, passing the float `0.0001` like this `[0.0].__iadd__(0.0001)`, then it assumes you are adding two iterables but the `0.0001` is not, hence the error you get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

**Note:**
The answer above was edited after @deceze comment to reflect that  `__iadd__` is the primary mechanism used here and not `operator.iadd()`. `operator.iadd([0.0], 0.0001)` is equivalent to `[0.0] += 0.0001` which ultimately ends up callig `__iadd__` from `list` class, so the outcome for `operator.iadd([0.0], 0.0001)` is the same: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

Comment: It’s really more like `[0.0].__iadd__(0.0001)`, the `operator` module is not the primary mechanism here… But yeah, generally your explanation is right.

Comment: @deceze thanks for the correction. I updated my answer to reflect `__iadd__` as the primary mechanism, see above.

Comment: To be *even* more nitpicky, it's something like `type([0.0]).__iadd__([0.0], 0.0001)`, but you get the idea… 

Answer (score 0):

i Found  following solution

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
x =[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
y = [[2],[4],[6],[8]]
w = [[1.477867], [0.]]
#define  y =k*x+b
def feed_forward(inputs,outputs, weights):
  out =np.dot(inputs,weights[0])+weights[1]
  squared_error =(np.square(out-outputs))
  return squared_error
def update_weights(inputs,outputs,weights,epochs):
  for epoch in range(epochs):
    org_loss =feed_forward(inputs,outputs,weights)
    wts_tmp = deepcopy(weights)
    wts_tmp2 = deepcopy(weights)
    for i in range(len(weights)): 
       wts_tmp[i][0] += 0.0001
       loss = feed_forward(inputs, outputs, wts_tmp)
       delta_loss = np.sum(org_loss - loss)/(0.0001*len(inputs))
       wts_tmp2[i][0]+= delta_loss*0.01 
       wts_tmp = deepcopy(weights)
    weights = deepcopy(wts_tmp2)
  return wts_tmp2
weigths_new =update_weights(x,y,w,10000)
print(weigths_new)
```

it gives me the following  answers
[[-0.00019999999990816253], [5.000449999999719]]